# How do I allow a JSON response in a mechanize test?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, mechanize

I have a web service that returns JSON responses when successful. Unfortunately, when I try to test this service via multi-mechanize, I get an error - "not viewing HTML". Obviously it's not viewing HTML, it's getting content clearly marked as JSON. How do I get mechanize to ignore this error and accept the JSON it's getitng back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out mechanize isn't set up to accept JSON responses out of the box. For a quick and dirty solution to this, update mechanize's _headersutil.py file (check /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mechanize).

In the is_html() method, change the line:

```
html_types = ["text/html"]
```

to read:

```
html_types = ["text/html", "application/json"]
```